# Lists in static classes generate warning, other data types don't

Tags: java, static, warnings

Upon writing a parameterized JUnit test case I came upon this warning when setting instance variables in the constructor:

`The static field ClassA.ListOfStrings should be accessed in a static way`

Offered solutions are:

`@SuppressWarnings("static-access")`

AND

`ClassA.ListOfStrings = ParamListOfStrings;`

instead of

`this.ListOfStrings = ParamListOfStrings;`

This warning occurs for self defined objects as well, but not for other data types (or a single `String`). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does happen to other data types that are **static**.

When accessing static field, it is better to use `ClassName.fieldName` instead of `myObj.fieldName`.

One reason is to get compilation error when changing the field to be non-static.

Comment: I totally overlooked the fact that my other data types weren't declared as static, thanks for pointing this out! I currently have a few fields as static (the lists, because they're being added data to in the static `getParameters()` method) and a few fields as non-static (they're being initialized in the constructor). Is is advised to make all fields static in this scenario?

Comment: Every field that is related to an instance, must be non-static. If you have a field you want to share with all your instances, you can use static (and probably instantiate it before the constructor and not inside it).

Answer (score 1):

The warning has nothing to do with the type of the static variable, but with the fact that you are qualifying your *static field access expression* with an instance of the owning class instead of with the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Static doesn't quite mean "shared by all instances" - it means "not related to a particular instance at all". In other words, you could get at the static field in class A without ever creating any instances.

You can do

```
ClassName.variable;
```

instead of

```
ClassName cn = new ClassName();
cn.variable;
```